# CustomspeechのlanguageModel

Tags: azure

MicrosoftAzureのCognitive speechで東京にサブスクリプションを行いました。目的は精度の高い音声認識を日本語で得るためです。

Custom Speech / Adaption data でlanguage Modelsにtmp.txtをimportしました。Failedという結果を得ました。tmp.txtにはひらがなでUTF-8 BOMで複数行の場合と１行の場合で書きました。改行キーはCR＋LF（windows)で書きました。

language Modelsのひな型があれば教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: [データを準備する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-customize-language-model#prepare-the-data) の **'\t' などの特殊文字や、Unicode 文字コード表 の U+00A1 より上のその他の UTF-8 文字は使用しません** と [その他の言語](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/prepare-transcription#other-languages) の **次の例では、ドイツ語を使用しています。 ただし、このガイドラインは、英語 (米国) または中国語以外のすべての言語に適用されます。** を合わせると、ひらがなは使えないのかもしれません。

Comment: 古い記事ですが、これが該当しそうです。[音声認識をカスタマイズできるMicrosoftのCustom Speech Serviceの使い方](https://qiita.com/tomohiku/items/ea392330c5ee7021de1f)